# How do I disable "swipe up for more" when watching videos on Twitter?

Tags: ios, twitter

On the official Twitter iPhone app, a distracting bar saying "swipe up for more" will often repeatedly pop up on the bottom of the screen while I'm trying to watch a video. I've tried to dismiss the prompt by swiping to a new video a few times, but the bar keeps coming back when I try to watch a different video.

How can I permanently disable the "swipe up for more" bar that appears when watching videos on Twitter?

[image: "swipe up for more" bar]